Volume Mounting Not working Docker Windows10
That's my Project Tree
Volume Mounting for windows 10 not working while it works on mac os.
Project/ -
|-Scalable-ChatApp(frontend)/
|-Scalable-ChatApp-backend/
    |-controllers/
    |-node_modules/
    |-dbSchema/
    |-apiGateway.js
    |-ca.pem
    |-dbinsertionkafka.js
    |-fetchService.js
    |-socketservice.js
    |-Dockerfile.apiGateway
    |-Dockerfile.dbinsertionkafka
    |-Dockerfile.fetchService
    |-Dockerfile.socketservice
    |-docker-compose.yml

docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  socketservice:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.socketservice
    image: socketservice-image
    command: ["nodemon", "/app/socketservice.js"]
    ports:
      - "4001:4001"
    volumes:
      - ./socketservice.js:/app/socketservice.js
      - ./ca.pem:/app/ca.pem 
    restart: always

  dbinsertion:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dbinsertionkafka
    image: dbinsertion-image
    command: ["nodemon", "/app/dbinsertionkafka.js"]
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
      - ./dbinsertionkafka.js:/app/dbinsertionkafka.js
      - ./ca.pem:/app/ca.pem 
    restart: always

  fetchservice:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.fetchService
    image: fetchservice-image
    command: ["nodemon", "/app/fetchService.js"]
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./fetchService.js:/app/fetchService.js
    restart: always

  apigateway:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.apigateway
    image: apigateway-image
    command: ["nodemon", "/app/apiGateway.js"]
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./apiGateway.js:/app/apiGateway.js
    restart: always


I created volume to see the changes immediately for local development but its not working. Its not giving any error and its not reflecting the changes. What is the solution ?

I have multiple microservices and using docker for that it would be helpful enough and mounting volume works for my mac but not here in windows
